# how to encrypt a 3-tier architecture communication

Tags: java, apache, security, jakarta-ee, 3-tier

I have a JavaEE app structured in a 2-tier architecture. 1st tier has a tomEE that handles https requests and serves the contents, relying on an oracle database in the 2nd tier.

Since the DB connection can be set to be secure and since I am using https, it's pretty safe (at least for these two aspects).

Now, I need to port this app into a 3-tier architecture and all channels must be secure. My first idea was to just move tomEE to the middle tier and add some apache httpd in the first tier, as a reverse proxy.

The problem is the communication between the first and second tier. If I've understood well, https is by design a protocol that ensures no MITM attacks, so httpd simply can't forward https.

OTOH, if both httpd have their own SSL certificates, I could keep the communication encrypted, but these certificates management would not be trivial.

I could just open an SSL tunnel from the 1st and 2nd tier, so TomEE could just run on plain http and let httpd deal with the HTTPS but I am not sure if this solution would scale or have an impact on performance.

Or I could try some EJB to EJB communication, using another TomEE in the 1st tier :-) but this does not seems right.

What would be the best approach for this situation?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need to convert the application from 2-tier to 3-tier?

Comment: Sounds like your application already is 3-tier. Or are you missing the presentation layer completely (or the business logic)?

Comment: It's quite a common approach to terminate SSL at a load balancer or reverse proxy. You _might_ even get better performance that way. It would certainly be easy to scale as they'll be pretty lightweight and you can horizontally scale independently at any tier.

Comment: @Thomas the application must follow the client's HW design

Comment: @Kayaman tomEE serves JSF and contains the transactional logic as EJBs, so you're right in a sense that these 2 tiers are in a single machine. If you know a good way to detach these two pieces, this may be a good solution too.

Comment: @arco444 That's true. In fact, there is a load balancer before the 1st tier :-) but I omitted it in this question for the sake of simplicity. Unfortunately, it's a pretty sensitive application so the client wants to bulletproof as much as possible

Comment: @Leo Well, three-tier architecture is considered to be different from two-tier (client-server), in that you have the presentation, logic and data separated. You're not transforming a 2-tier architecture to 3-tier by adding a reverse proxy. Anyways, if your client insists on keeping all the communication secure, you'll be forced to deal with multiple SSL certificates or other such solution. If I were in your position, I'd first talk to the client about whether it's truly a risk that an attacker can penetrate your internal network to listen to non-SSL traffic.

Comment: Assuming of course that there is an internal network with a DMZ in between.

Comment: @Kayaman right, but supposing I can't change things, my question remains. What would be a nice approach given these constraints?

Comment: I don't see any "nice" approach here. If you can't trust any of your servers, and need to secure all of your channels, then SSL (or IPSec) is what you'll need. However, if you can't trust your servers, is this really enough?